# Moving web service references to other folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, web-services

Is it possible to have web service references in other folders than "Service References" without loosing IDE features?

I want to have ExternalWebService1 in a folder like ExternalSystem1\WebServices

Comment: I  think no.You can't do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is, the Service References folder is a design-time only folder.  When your website gets published, the folder is usually empty.  This would hold true if you moved it anyway.  What are the benefits of moving it?

Comment: I have several different external subsystems, so it's just to organize everything by subsystem.

Comment: Just to accept the message... The real answer is anishmarokey's "No"